# how to change level box to make it unavailable if the highscore is 0 or not played before

Tags: lua

I have this 3 boxes amount of levels, per box contains level number and highscore, I want to ask how to change the level 2 and 3 cant be clicked before clearing first level.
--amountOfLevels = 3

```
local i
for i=1, amountOfLevels do
    if i <= #levelScores then
        --First the sqaure
        local sqaure = display.newImageRect(screenGroup, "images/block_green_brick.png", 50, 50)
        sqaure.x = xStart + (rowControl*xOffset)
        sqaure.y = yStart + (yControl*yOffset); sqaure.id = i
        sqaure:addEventListener("tap", levelTouched)

        --Then the number/score text.
        local number = display.newText(screenGroup, i, 0,0, native.sytemFontBold, 18)
        number.x = sqaure.x; number.y = sqaure.y-10
        local score = display.newText(screenGroup, levelScores[i], 0,0, native.sytemFontBold, 17)
        score.x = sqaure.x; score.y = number.y+24
    else --tried to change tobe elseif #levelScores == 0 but doesnt work
        local sqaure = display.newImageRect(screenGroup, "images/block_green_question.png", 50, 50)
        sqaure.x = xStart + (rowControl*xOffset)
        sqaure.y = yStart + (yControl*yOffset)
    end

    --Control variables.
    rowControl = rowControl + 1
    if rowControl == amountPerRow then
        yControl = yControl + 1
        rowControl = 0
    end
end
```

Comment: Need more information to be able to help you. Do you already have a function to handle the touch? Are you using some kind of API/framework for the UI?

Comment: local function levelTouched(event)
        currentLevel = event.target.id
        storyboard.gotoScene( "game", "slideLeft", 400 )
    end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the lack of code, I'm guessing here by what I think your code is doing.

To give you EXACTLY what you asked:

```
local function levelTouched(event)
    local lv = event.target.id
    if lv==1 or tonumber(levelScores[1])>0 then
        currentLevel = lv
        storyboard.gotoScene( "game", "slideLeft", 400 )
    end
end
```

Now if you want to make any level unavailable if the previous one has not been cleared:

```
local function levelTouched(event)
    local lv = event.target.id
    if lv==1 or tonumber(levelScores[lv-1])>0 then
        currentLevel = lv
        storyboard.gotoScene( "game", "slideLeft", 400 )
    end
end
```

Comment: Right, that is because `levelScores` is composed of `string`. Just added the `tonumber` to be able to compare it. @MagMell

Comment: --var
local _W = display.contentWidth 
local _H = display.contentHeight
local amountOfLevels = 3 
local amountPerRow = 3 
local levelScores = {} 

local dbPath = system.pathForFile("levelScores.db3", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local db = sqlite3.open( dbPath );

    --loop 
    local rowInt = 1
    for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM scores") do
        levelScores[rowInt] = row.highscore
        rowInt = rowInt + 1
    end
    db:close()

Comment: Well, I guess I can only help you seeing more of your code. Is the `id` a number that identifies the level, starting from 1? And are levelScores the scores of each level, written as `string`, when `0` means it was not cleared? If yes it should work, since `goToScene` is called only when the score is bigger than zero.